# Function in template.php to override Profile2

Tags: theming, users

How can I make Profile2's overrides (profile2.tpl.php) work? Do I have to include a function "mytheme_preprocess_page" with "theme_hook_suggestions" in template.php?

Comment: Copying the profile2.tpl.php in your theme should allow you overriding and you do not need to have theme suggestion for that

Comment: Thanks arpitr. That's what I am trying to do, including a simple text in it to see any change, but nothing happens...

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I did. I try to insert a simple h3 in this template but it does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have crossed checked the suggested way on my local and I can see it working.Here are some pointers.I copied the profile2.tpl.php present inside profile2 module and paste it inside site default theme templates folder and finally clear the caches.In order to see what profile is working I added some test content on both templates and found content from profile2.tpl.php from my theme is working.

As a side Note:You can make theming experience far more easy using [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module,

> Firebug for Drupal themeing.Note that this module injects markers into
>   the DOM to do its magic. This may cause some themes to behave
>   erratically and less capable browsers may make it worse (especially
>   IE)/. Enable it when needed, and disable it afterwards.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem you had,please add as an answer will be help for others as well